# In a ring with identity, the maximal ideal is unique one?

Tags: abstract-algebra

One of Propositions in Dummit's textbook says this:

In a ring with identity $1\neq 0$ every proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal.

So can I conclude that the maximal ideal is unique in this case?

Or maybe not?

Comment: Are you so sure?

Comment: I'm not so sure so I posted the question here :)

Comment: Not. For example the ideal generated by $6$ extends to two maximal ideals, the one generated by $2$ and the one generated by $3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $R = C[0,1]$, then the maximal ideals are all of the form
$$
M_{x} := \{f \in C[0,1] : f(x) = 0\}
$$
One for each $x \in [0,1]$, so certainly not unique.

Answer (score 5):

Nope.

Every ideal is contained in a maximal ideal (proven using Zorn's lemma), but in general this is definitely not unique.

Consider $(6) = 6\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. $(6)$ is contained in both $(3) = 3\mathbb{Z}$ and $(2) = 2\mathbb{Z}$ (both of which are maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$.

[Note: $(2)$ and $(3)$ are maximal since $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ are fields.]

Comment: You can actually use the same argument in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, just to get a small example.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. The theorem just says "contained," not "properly contained," so any maximal ideal trivially satisfies this condition: it is contained in itself. For example, $\Bbb{Z}$ has infinitely many maximal ideals: one for each prime.

Rings with exactly one maximal ideal do, however, have a name: they are called local rings.